# Outlook CSS background-color of table cell

Tags: css, outlook, css-selectors

The following simple CSS works in several mail clients, but the color and font-weight are not being applied in Outlook 2016.

```
<style type="text/css">
table {width: 100%}
td:first-child {background-color: #FFDAB9 ; width: 17%; font-weight:bold}
</style>
```

The width setting **is** being honored, so I conclude  `first-child` pseudo-class is supported.

How to control the `background-color` and the `font-weight`?

Comment: Despite your conclusion it seems that `first-child`  may not be supported - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/

Comment: Very odd.  Not sure how the `width` setting is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

The WC3 Standard for background color in a table is [bgcolor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_bgcolor.asp) (deprecated) and [background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

```
td:first-child {bgcolor:#FFDAB9; background:#FFDAB9;}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/jk9ejc6q/2/)

Comment: What do you make of this? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: I don't believe it work when rendered as a table in the outlook client.

Comment: Perhaps try an inline style: "Do not use CSS classes - always use inline CSS " Here is a design guide: http://www.activecampaign.com/email-design-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Because Outlook uses Word to render emails, it has very limited CSS support,
you can fond in this website: [Campagign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/email-client/outlook-2007-16/) indicates that `:first-child` CSS selector doesn't support by Outlook 2016.

To fix this, try to use inline CSS style or give your HTML element a class name could work.

Happy coding!